# Explicit bijection of $\Bbb R \longleftrightarrow (\Bbb R - \{ 0 \})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking for a clean bijection between the real line and the set of reals that have multiplicative inverses.
 $$f : \Bbb R \longleftrightarrow (\Bbb R - \{ 0 \})$$
I can construct a bijection of the right sort, but it is a tad messy:

$$
f(0) = \frac12 \\
(x \in R \wedge n\in \Bbb Z^+  \wedge x = \frac1{n+1}) \implies f(x) = \frac1{n+2} \\ (x \in R \wedge \forall n\in \Bbb Z^+  ( x \neq \frac1{n+1}) ) \implies f(x) = x
$$

In this bijection we move zero to the first proper Egyptian fraction $\frac12$, slide $\frac12$ to the next Egyptian fraction $\frac13$, and so forth.

But I'm looking for something "cleaner," along the same sort of lines as the bijection of $f : \Bbb R \longleftrightarrow (-1,1) \,\,| \,\,f(x) = \frac2{\pi}\tan^{-1}$ x.

It seems as if trying to cut out just one point is more messy than mapping the real line to a finite open interval; probably in general bijective mappings of  an uncountable open set to a set which is not open is inherently messier.  But I'm trying to quantify that notion.

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than that. It's a bit simpler perhaps if you set $f(n)=n+1$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Any bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^\times$ cannot be that "clean" since one space is connected and the other isn't.

Comment: @AndreaMori: It's not quite so simple. For instance, a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R-[0,1)$ is easy. The point is that $\Bbb R-\{0\}$ is a disjoint union of _open_ sets.

Comment: You can also map each interval $[n,n+1)$ to the interval $(n,n+1]$ through $x\mapsto $2n+1-x$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ if you want piecewise continuity.

Comment: What does "clean" mean?  Why don't you just do $f(x) = \begin{cases} x &\text{if } x\not \in \mathbb N \cup\{0\}\\x+1&\text{if } x\in \mathbb N\cup\{0\}\end{cases}$

Comment: @fleablood with that $f(x)$ what is $f^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: @MarkFischler  $0$ isn't *in* the codomain so there is no $f^{-1}(0)$.  That was the *entire* point.  This is a bijection between $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R-\{0\}$.  $0 \not \in \mathbb R-\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
\phi:\Bbb R^{>0}\longrightarrow\Bbb R^\times
$$
the piecewise linear function that sends

- the interval $(0,1)$ onto itself;
- the interval $[1,2)$ onto the interval $[-1,0)$;
- the interval $[2,3)$ onto the interval $[1,2)$;
- the interval $[3,4)$ onto the interval $[-2,1)$;
- and so on.

The function $\phi$ is a bijection. Now define
$$
f(x)=\phi(e^x).
$$

Comment: I think you must mean $f(x)=\phi(e^x)$.

Comment: @TonyK. of course! Edited

Comment: For this to be a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R - \{0\}$ (the latter is in fact the range of $\phi(e^x)$ so that part is good), there would have to be some $x$ such that $\phi(e^x) = 0$.  And there is no such $x$.

Comment: If the range is $\mathbb R- \{0\}$ and $0$ is not in the range, it is *FORBIDDEN* for there to be a $\phi(e^x) = 0$.  It is certainly *NOT* true that there must by a $\phi(e^x) =0$.  It is absolutely essential that there *NOT* be one.

Comment: @MarkFischler: The exponential function is a bicontinuous bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^{>0}$ (in fact also a group isomorphism), and $\phi$ as stated is a bijection. Thus $\phi\circ{\rm exp}$ is a bijection.